# Outlook 2007 (2003) Rule: "Mark As Read" "Move to a specific folder" Envelope displays in system tray after message is read

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, notification-area

After creating a rule in Outlook 2007 (or 2003) (on Windows XP) which will change certain messages to "Mark as Read" and then "Move to a Specific Folder" and the rule is executed the notification icon in the System Tray will  (little envelope) will remain after the rule is complete.

How can you add a rule in a way that will accomplish the "Mark as Read" and "Move to a Specific Folder" action as well as NOT show the System Tray icon for unread message?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This information was obtained from this message board.
http://forums.techguy.org/business-applications/695618-outlook-2003-mark-read-rule.html

The method that worked for me was as listed in the thread on the above site.

Adjust the rule by splitting into two sepearte rules.

Rule 1 should mark the message as read.
Rule 2 should move the message to the specific folder.

You should be certian that the rules are listed in the order above (rule 1 showing before rule 2)

Comment: I can confirm that this works for Outlook 2016 on Windows 10.