# Outlook 2010 Quick Steps "mark as read" action: new mail notification still shows in system tray

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010

Hopefully my title says it all:
I created a Quick Steps shortcut to

1. Mark a message as read, then
2. Move to a specified folder.

It does all that.

But, the new mail notification still appears in my system tray. I then have to open & close the message to make the system tray notification disappear. It completely defeats the purpose of a "Quick step".

**Q:** Is there any way to prevent the new mail icon?

Comment: Maybe the issue is related to http://superuser.com/questions/39138/outlook-2007-2003-rule-mark-as-read-move-to-a-specific-folder-envelope-di?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You could always customize the notification area to "Hide Icon and Notifications" for Outlook, that way you'll never see the icon or notification.

Comment: Ya, I know, thanks, but that way I'll never know if new mail is there unless I deliberately go to Outlook to look :\

Comment: Then I'm not sure what you're trying to prevent from showing up. Are you talking about the little envelope that is in the system tray?

Comment: Yes, that. I don't want to create a rule that deals with this particular email without me knowing, because I do need to see them when they come in. Hence the Quick Step process. I see it, I select it, I "Quick Step" it (which marks it as read and files it away). But then the icon in my sys tray still sits there even though I've dealt with the only mail that has come in.

Comment: Instead of a quick step, why don't you use a rule? When a message arrives and you use a rule to move and mark it as read, you don't get a notification of the message. That way, only messages that aren't ruled off show up with notifications.

Comment: But wouldn't a Rule mean that the message will be marked/moved without me seeing/knowing? I need to at least see that this particluar type of message has arrived, but then just need a quick way to deal with it.

Comment: Yes, that what the rule would do. So you want to be notified so you can deal with the message, but then you don't want the notification icon to tell you that you need to deal with it? What you are asking for is very confusing.

Comment: Then I'm not explaining myself very well. I apologise. Yes I want to see that this message has come in, yes I want to deal with it, but once it's dealt with I want the notification in the sys tray to go away. What happens right now is I see the mail, I deal with it, but the notification still sits down there. Why doesn't it go away when the mail has been marked as read and moved to another folder??

Comment: It's happened to others as well: [social.technet.microsoft.com...](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/9a80d777-c2f6-423c-80d7-f43f698fa9ec/outlook-2010-quick-steps-mark-as-read-action-and-new-mail-notification)

Comment: It was also mentioned by someone [here at superuser.com](http://superuser.com/questions/601602/outlook-rule-to-not-display-a-notification-for-certain-messages?rq=1) who has a different issue (but still mentions the sticky notification icon)